# put a picture on tabHost

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a host tab and I would only put an image on a tab.
I found this method:

```
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1").setContent(R.id.tab1)
            .setIndicator("Tab 1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.book)));
```

that provides text and image, but no good. How should I do?

EDIT

I tried putting in main.xml:

```
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                        <ImageView 
                            android:id="@+id/x2"
                            android:src="@drawable/book"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



                    </LinearLayout>
```

I put in the activity the following statement:

```
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1").setContent(R.id.tab1));
```

but the program go crash...

Comment: Please share any image. What you want to display??

Comment: the image is "book.png", contained in the res, as currently seen accompanied by the word "tab 1"

Comment: do u want only the image to be displayed

Comment: tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1").setContent(R.id.tab1)
            .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.book)));

Comment: I tried but it remains an empty space below:)

Comment: are u running this application on 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked around for similar question relating to your problem, I think if you take a look at the answers provided in the following question, you may find some answers to help you:

[How to change the Tabs Images in the TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507718/how-to-change-the-tabs-images-in-the-tabhost-in-android)

Hope this helps.