# How to get this tab image to take up the full area

Tags: android, tabs

[image]

In this picture I am trying to get the image to take up the whole top and bottom area that is black.  I looked into these links here but I am just not having any luck so far:

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

[Android remove space between tabs in tabwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799320/android-remove-space-between-tabs-in-tabwidget/5804436#5804436)

[How to change the Tabs Images in the TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507718/how-to-change-the-tabs-images-in-the-tabhost-in-android)

The code:

MainActivity:

```
// Add the Tabs/////////////////////////////////////////////
    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b_news));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("Library");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    specs.setIndicator("Community");
    th.addTab(specs);
```

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/libraryListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/communityListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was in the links I provided.  I just needed to look a little bit more into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(params);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(params);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setLayoutParams(params);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setLayoutParams(params);
```