# Custom tab bar in android?

Tags: android

I want to display the bottom tab bar as MAC system dock menu

[image]

How to achieve this dock menu in android

Answer (score 2):

`TabHost` not provide to much facility to customize there layout. So what i did, I create a layout as I wanted with combination of ImageView and transfer it's click to relative `TabWidget`. I created layout like below.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

        <include 
            android:id="@+id/customtab"
            layout="@layout/customtablayout"/>
      <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

      </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here `customtablayout`  is my layout with images as tab(you can add anithing). and when I click to a image, I called `tabHost.setCurrentTab(index);`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check (tab whith image) : [How to change the Tabs Images in the TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507718/how-to-change-the-tabs-images-in-the-tabhost)
2. You applay mirror effect to your image
3. Set Animation for resizing the view [Resizing layouts programmatically (as animation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140571/resizing-layouts-programatically-as-animation)